# Android draw image performance

Tags: android, bitmap, frame-rate

I'm making a simple game very similar to Pong. The main mechanic in the game involves swiping the screen to draw an image over the background, and then subsequently sprites are drawn on top of those two things.

I am running into performance issues, and Im not sure why. I have disabled all the drawing functions except the one that draws the foreground image (above the background but below the sprites). This is causing the problem.

The foreground image Im using is a 30kb png. Im loading my image only once on startup (RGB565 format), then using:

```
@Override
public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage)Image).bitmap, x, y, null);
```

to draw the image to the canvas in my Draw method. This runs VERY slowly for some reason (running on my Nexus 7). If I use the drawRect method instead, it runs perfectly, so it has something to do with the way Im drawing my imported image. Is drawBitmap a bad way to do this? Do I need to learn this OpenGL stuff for such a simple game?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem, my situation might be relevant, but probably not.

I was using a 4mb wav file as my theme song for the title page, and forgot to release the memory when the game starts. Im getting smooth fps now!

Answer (score 0):

As your code segment is short, I am not sure how you called that method.

If you are going to draw a very responsive View, you should use SurfaceView to draw the content in onDraw(Canvas canvas) method.

Since you are writing a game, how often is the location of the pong being updated? Is this update performed in a AsyncTask or Runnable? You can reduce excessive calling of onDraw by  calling invalidate() only if the position of sprites are updated.